# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utils')

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I tried to deploy my contract and got this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utils')

I tried to use a few versions of ethers, but no luck.

I use utils here:

```
const { developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { network, ethers } = require("../hardhat.config")

const BASE_FEE = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.25")
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The import is wrong:

```
const { network, ethers } = require("../hardhat.config")
```

This should be:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
```

If you're using hardhat

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
```

If you're using ethers directly.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'computeAddress')` I had this piece of code `const {ethers} = require('ethers')` - *like @Adam Boudj suggested* - and using it this way: `const address = ethers.utils.computeAddress(key, index)`.

When I changed the import to `const { computeAddress } = require("ethers")` everything worked fine.

So I think if you change your import to `const { parseEther} = require("ethers")` and use it this way `const BASE_FEE = parseEther("0.25")` your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in my case was with hardhat config file.

I was using **[hardhat-deploy](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy)** to deploy the contract and missed to import **hardhat-waffle** in *config* file
Add this line on top of your **hardhat-config-file**

```js
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
```

**My entire setup**
deploy.js

```js
const { network, ethers, getChainId } = require('hardhat');
const { devChains, networkConfig } = require('../helper-hardhat-config');
const { verify } = require('../utils/verify');

const AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther('2');
```

hardhat.config.js

```js
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan');
require('hardhat-deploy');
require('dotenv').config();
```

package.json

```js
"devDependencies": {
        "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers@^0.3.0-beta.13",
        "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.0.0",
        "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.1",
        "chai": "^4.3.4",
        "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.0",
        "ethers": "^5.5.1",
        "hardhat": "^2.6.7",
        "hardhat-contract-sizer": "^2.4.0",
        "hardhat-deploy": "^0.9.29",
        "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.7",
        "prettier": "^2.4.1",
        "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.0.0-beta.19",
        "solhint": "^3.3.6",
        "solidity-coverage": "^0.7.13"
    },
```

Note: Don't use ethers version 6 as its unstable